# how to locally generate the packaging files (*.cspkg, *.cscfg and *.csdef )

Tags: azure, cloud

I changed the project from **classic** to **extended support** (as recommended). Now there are 4 configuration files required when importing via azure portal.
These files are *.cspkg, *.cscfg and *.csdef zip

How to generate from VS2022?

I know I can directly deploy to the azure service but looking for manual process

Comment: I didn't find an option to create classic project in VS 2022.I can only see the [Extended support](https://i.imgur.com/KiLfE1D.png).I can see the 3 [configuration files](https://i.imgur.com/yZ9yhxb.png) when I create the Project.

Comment: How you have created the classic project ?

Comment: Hello Harshita,
The option “publish (extended support)” is only available because the default “classic” will be deprecated by 2024.

Comment: Did you find an option for `Package/Pack` in your existing Project ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an option to create classic project in VS 2022.I can only see the  [Extended support](https://i.imgur.com/KiLfE1D.png).

To manually create the configuration files, right click on the project folder and select `Package`.

[image]

- Build configuration specifies the folder to create the configuration files.
- The configuration files will be generated in the `bin` => `Debug/Release` folder.
- Here I have selected the below settings

```cs
Service configuration - local 
Build configuration Debug
```

I got the below error

> ```cs
> WAT001 : At least one web or worker role is required but none could be found
> ```

- I have added the new Web Role Project.

[image]

[image]

- Now Iam able to generate the configuration files.
  [image]
- You can see the 3 files `.cspkg`,`.cscfg` and  `.csdef` are generated in the `bin` => `Debug` => `app.publish` folder.

[image]